# How to delete empty space between form elements

Tags: html, css

How I can delete empty space between search `input box` and the `go button`? I've prepared jsfiddle with code sample. Link - [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2nwp36nj/)

**Screenshot:**
[image]
**HTML:**

```
<div class="blablabla">
<form id="search_mini" action="#" method="get">
    <div class="form-search">
        <!--<label for="search"></label>-->
        <input id="search" value="SEARCH" type="text" name="q" class="input-text" maxlength="128" autocomplete="off">
        <button type="submit" title="GO" class="button"><span><span>GO</span></span>
        </button>
        <div id="search_autocomplete" class="search-autocomplete" style="display: none;"></div>
    </div>
</form>
```

**CSS:**

```
#search_mini {
    width: 268px;
}
.form-search input {
    border-color: #7d7c7c;
    height: 30px;
    width: 150px;
    padding:0;
}
.form-search button.button {
    background: url(../images/bg.gif) 0 0 repeat-x;
    font-size: 12px;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 0;
    height: 36px;
    min-width: 84px;
}
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: try with float:left; for all elements

Comment: Tried, still will be 1-2 px gap, so it's not a possible solution unfortunately.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/2nwp36nj/1/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may try `margin-left`:

```css
#search_mini {
  width: 268px;
}
.form-search input {
  border-color: #7d7c7c;
  height: 30px;
  width: 150px;
  padding: 0;
}
.form-search button.button {
  background: url(../images/bg.gif) 0 0 repeat-x;
  font-size: 12px;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 0;
  height: 36px;
  min-width: 84px;
  margin-left: -4px;/* put as your need */
}
```

```html
<div class="blablabla">
  <form id="search_mini" action="#" method="get">
    <div class="form-search">
      <!--<label for="search"></label>-->
      <input id="search" value="SEARCH" type="text" name="q" class="input-text" maxlength="128" autocomplete="off">
      <button type="submit" title="GO" class="button"><span><span>GO</span></span>
      </button>
      <div id="search_autocomplete" class="search-autocomplete" style="display: none;"></div>
    </div>
  </form>
```

Comment: Still there is a gap, but I needed to make them stick together to each other.

Comment: Negative margin left looks more like a turn arround than a real solution, will probably give different result on different browsers.

Answer (score 0):

are suggested just such a button then she together with the form  [DEMO](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/Bdkpc)

```
<form class="form-wrapper cf">
    <input type="text" placeholder="search" required>
    <button type="submit">GO</button>
</form>


.cf:before, .cf:after{
    content:"";
    display:table;
}

.cf:after{
    clear:both;
}

.cf{
    zoom:1;
}    


.form-wrapper {
    width: 450px;
    padding: 15px;
    margin: 150px auto 50px auto;
    background: #444;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,.2);
    border-radius: 10px;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.4) inset, 0 1px 0 rgba(255,255,255,.2);
}



.form-wrapper input {
    width: 330px;
    height: 20px;
    padding: 10px 5px;
    float: left;    
    font: bold 15px 'lucida sans', 'trebuchet MS', 'Tahoma';
    border: 0;
    background: #eee;
    border-radius: 3px 0 0 3px;      
}

.form-wrapper input:focus {
    outline: 0;
    background: #fff;
    box-shadow: 0 0 2px rgba(0,0,0,.8) inset;
}

.form-wrapper input::-webkit-input-placeholder {
   color: #999;
   font-weight: normal;
   font-style: italic;
}

.form-wrapper input:-moz-placeholder {
    color: #999;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: italic;
}

.form-wrapper input:-ms-input-placeholder {
    color: #999;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: italic;
}    


.form-wrapper button {
    overflow: visible;
    position: relative;
    float: right;
    border: 0;
    padding: 0;
    cursor: pointer;
    height: 40px;
    width: 110px;
    font: bold 15px/40px 'lucida sans', 'trebuchet MS', 'Tahoma';
    color: #fff;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    background: #d83c3c;
    border-radius: 0 3px 3px 0;      
    text-shadow: 0 -1px 0 rgba(0, 0 ,0, .3);
}   

.form-wrapper button:hover{     
    background: #e54040;
}   

.form-wrapper button:active,
.form-wrapper button:focus{   
    background: #c42f2f;
    outline: 0;   
}

.form-wrapper button:before { 
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    border-width: 8px 8px 8px 0;
    border-style: solid solid solid none;
    border-color: transparent #d83c3c transparent;
    top: 12px;
    left: -6px;
}

.form-wrapper button:hover:before{
    border-right-color: #e54040;
}

.form-wrapper button:focus:before,
.form-wrapper button:active:before{
        border-right-color: #c42f2f;
}      

.form-wrapper button::-moz-focus-inner { 
    border: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

Comment: Still there is a gap, but I needed to make them stick together to each other.

Answer (score 0):

add `float:left` to you .form-search input element

example: http://jsfiddle.net/2nwp36nj/2/

```css
#search_mini {
    width: 268px;
}
.form-search input {
    border-color: #7d7c7c;
    height: 30px;
    width: 150px;
    padding:0;
    float: left;
}
.form-search button.button {
    background: url(../images/bg.gif) 0 0 repeat-x;
    font-size: 12px;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 0;
    height: 36px;
    min-width: 84px;
}
```

```html
<div class="blablabla">
    <form id="search_mini" action="#" method="get" _lpchecked="1">
        <div class="form-search">
            <!--<label for="search"></label>-->
            <input id="search" value="SEARCH" type="text" name="q" class="input-text" maxlength="128" autocomplete="off">
            <button type="submit" title="GO" class="button"><span><span>GO</span></span>
            </button>
            <div id="search_autocomplete" class="search-autocomplete" style="display: none;"></div>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Still there is a gap, but I needed to make them stick together to each other.

Comment: I don't see any gap. they are exactly aligned. if you want the elements to over-lap you should add a negative margin-left.

Answer (score 0):

use float left for both of the elements input and button also you need to give a width for button as well. It looks like it is working in the below code.

http://jsfiddle.net/2nwp36nj/3/

```
#search_mini {
    width: 368px;
}
.form-search input, .form-search button {
    border-color: #7d7c7c;
    height: 30px;
    width: 150px;
    padding:0;
    float: left;
}
.form-search button.button {
    background: url(../images/bg.gif) 0 0 repeat-x;
    font-size: 12px;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 0;
    height: 36px;
    min-width: 84px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply add this to your elements :

```
.form-search input,
.form-search button.button
{
    display: block;
    float: left;
}
```

Your space is actually due to a whitespace.

Answer (score 0):

Another working solution: you must insert comment between `input` tag and `button` tag. Like this:

```
<input id="search" value="SEARCH" type="text" name="q" class="input-text" maxlength="128" autocomplete="off"><!--
--><button type="submit" title="GO" class="button"><span><span>GO</span></span>
```